# how can i get image id inside my controller while selecting on a image in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

how can i get a image id inside my controller while selecting on a image

My html file

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
   <li class="span3" ng-repeat="reward in rewardData.results">
     <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
       <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{reward.image}}" />
     </a>
   </li>
</ul>
<div style="display:block;width:60%;">
  <a href="#invite" class="btn btn-theme invitefr" ng-click="selectPrizes()"> Save Challenge and Continue</a>
</div>
```

it will show multiple images, i want a image id inside my controller while some one select any image, can anyone know how to implement it?

my controller :

```
app.controller("PrizesController", ["$location", "$scope","authenticationSvc","$http", function ($location, $scope,authenticationSvc, $http) {
    console.log("inside prize controller");

    var token = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();
    var config = {
        headers: {
            'h5cAuthToken': token.accessToken,
            'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose'
        }
    };

     $http.get("http://IPandPortnumber/ccp-services/challengereward/allRewards", config)
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.rewardData = response.data;

        });

    $scope.selectPrizes = function () {
      // some block of codes       
       $location.path("/invite");
    }
}]);
```

Comment: is there element called id or something inside rewardData array

Comment: @Ranawaka, it is rewardId inside rewardData

Comment: @ashishkumar- Is there unique id for image???

Comment: @MaheshBhusanoor yes each image has it's unique id, actually i have updated my question, i want a image id after selecting image and clicking **save challenge and continue** button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this inside your controller

```
  $scope.imgId='';
  $scope.getImgId= function (id) {
   console.log(id);
   $scope.imgId=id;
 }


  $scope.selectPrizes = function () {
  // You will get selected img id here  
   console.log($scope.imgId);
   $location.path("/invite");
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahesh Bhusanoor, as i am very new to angularjs so ask this silly question but hope this post will helpful for people who are new in angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the image id to getImgId(reward.id) function

```
 <ul class="thumbnails">
   <li class="span3" ng-repeat="reward in rewardData.results">
    <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,{{reward.image}}" ng-click="getImgId(reward.id)"/>
  </a>
 </li>
 </ul>
<div style="display:block;width:60%;">
   <a href="#invite" class="btn btn-theme invitefr" ng-  click="selectPrizes()"> Save Challenge and Continue</a>
 </div>

  //inside controller
  $scope.getImgId= function (id) {
  console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"